# Smart banner is showing on all devices(Iphone 6, Iphone 7, Ipad) except for Iphone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, smartbanner

Smart banner is showing on all devices(Iphone 6, Iphone 7, Ipad) except for Iphone 5s.
IOS version is 10.
I reset the iphone and cleared all the browser's data, but still having same issue.

The app identifier is correct, The used meta tag :

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=APP_ID">
```

Note: When I replaced the app id with another one for a working smart banner, it's works fine.

any clue please ?

Comment: Only works for modern iPhones (6 and higher) as far as I know

Comment: It's working for other website banners...